# Recursively list directories, c++

Tags: c++, list

I'm accessing a directory from my cross-platform c++ code. I know that this directory has three sub directories, but their names are randomly generated.

What I want is a list with the names of these directories (not files!) as type std::string.
I would very much like to avoid using libraries, such as boost or qt, and keep to standard c++, if possible.

Comment: There are no functionality in C++ (yet) to handle directories and directory walking. Either use a cross-platform library such as Boost, or code your own classes, that uses the native functionality of each platform.

Comment: filesystem stuff is platform specific, you can't perform such tasks without interfacing your program with something that is not portable, boost::filesystem let's you perform this task while abstracting the platform, it's a big plus.

Comment: As said, you need platform-specific code to access filesystem, so you need either `#ifdef`s for all the OSes supported by your app, or use some cross-platform library that have those `#ifdef`s inside. There are several libraries for this, Qt and boost are two of them as mentioned in comments, you can choose what you want

Comment: There have been many questions as how to find files, like the one you mention Dariusz. Not folders. And no libraries allowed, that's unfortunately why I can't use boost! :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rolled my own... effectively implementing a "findFirst" and "findNext" approach.  On Windows I used `_findfirst` and `_findnext` and the `_finddata_t` results can be utilized to determine if it's a directory or not (for recursion).  On *nix platforms I used `opendir` and `readdir` then used `stat` to determine if it was a directory.

Comment: Thank you very much. These _finds are exactly what i was looking for!